# Android: how to configure sizing of a custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying to create a custom horizontal layout with the goal to have a TextView to the left of an ImageView, containing a icon which depicts a certain status. The ImageView is to kept in a square dimension, with it's height and width equal to the height of the text in the TextView. Issues continue to persist, however, such as the text height not being set as specified in the layout xml file and an unknown padding existing after the ImageView. These problem can be seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEbU0.png), with the red indicating the unknown padding and the blue indicating the text size inconsistency where both where set to 12sp. The font sizing and padding issues need to be fixed so the layout can be properly added to a grid layout, which will contain a grid of these custom layouts.

**StatusIcon.java**

```
//This is part of the java class that extends ImageView to resize the Icon
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
    super.onMeasure(width, height);

    int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    setMeasuredDimension(measuredHeight, measuredHeight);
}
```

**StatusIndicator.java**

```
//This is the java class for the custom layout.
public class StatusIndicator extends LinearLayout {

    private TextView label;
    private StatusIcon statusLed;
    private CharSequence labelText;
    private float labelTextSize;

    public enum Status {
        GOOD,
        WARNING,
        CRITICAL
    }

    /*
     * Removed the basic required class constructors to save space.
     */

    private void getAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.StatusIndicator);
        labelText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.StatusIndicator_label);
        labelTextSize = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.StatusIndicator_labelSize, 0);
        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    private void initializeViews(Context context){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_status_indicator, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        //Setup UI elements in layout
        label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_statusIndicatorLabel);
        statusLed = (StatusIcon) findViewById(R.id.imageView_statusIndicatorLed);
        label.setText(labelText);

        if(labelTextSize > 0){
            label.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, labelTextSize);
        }
    }

    public void setStatus(StatusIndicator.Status status){
        switch (status){
            case GOOD:
                statusLed.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_status_panel_good);
                break;
            case WARNING:
                statusLed.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_status_panel_warning);
                break;
            case CRITICAL:
                statusLed.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_status_panel_critical);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**view_status_indicator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:parentTag="LinearLayout"
    tools:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_statusIndicatorLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:text="@string/default_title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

    <com.css_design.android_quickbridge.ui.home.status_panel.StatusIcon
        android:id="@+id/imageView_statusIndicatorLed"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|end"

        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_status_panel_critical"/>
    </merge>
```

Comment: Would you be willing to use android standard components if they could give you the same behavior, or are you required to create your own custom view?

Comment: @BenP. I would be willing to use standard components. I'm just new to Android and trying to figure things out. The main issue is that there'll be 16 of these StatusIndicators in a grid, and 2 grids in an activity, so I want to localize as much as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this problem by using `ConstraintLayout` instead of creating a custom view implementation.

`ConstraintLayout` allows you to specify an aspect ratio for its children, which takes care of wanting to make sure your `ImageView` is always exactly square. `ConstraintLayout` also allows you to specify height or width based on sibling views (by combining a dimension of `0dp` with `top` and `bottom` (or `left` and `right`) constraints).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ccf">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:text="hello world"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

(Background color added to the `ConstraintLayout` to show that it's not any larger than its contents).